# Duplicating multiple rows with a single query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query that works successfully.

```
INSERT INTO assignments (id, task_id, item_id, started, completed, result, status, marker_id) 
SELECT $1, task_id, item_id, NULL, completed, result, 'QUEUE', NULL
FROM assignments
WHERE assignments.id = $2
RETURNING id;
```

It duplicates one line by changing some values.

Now I need to insert a lot of lines. I do it this way, but I have a problem with it.

```
INSERT INTO assignments (id, task_id, item_id, started, completed, result, status, marker_id) 
SELECT UNNEST($1::uuid[]), task_id, item_id, NULL, completed, result, 'QUEUE', NULL
FROM assignments
WHERE assignments.id = ANY ($2::uuid[]);
```

Error: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "assignment_pk"`
but I don't send duplicates

Comment: What's your `assignment_pk` unique constraint? could you show us?

Comment: You are creating duplicates because there is nothing that ties a given element of the `$1` array with a single element in the `$2` array.